# Contradiction of special theory of relativity and quantum mechanics

Tags: special-relativity, quantum-mechanics

Why do special theory of relativty (with the core message of E=mc²) and quantum mechanics do not go together? Why is the special theory of relativity in the quantum model not valid?
Can anyone list some reasons or explain it on examples?

---

Edit: The question is based on mixing up something I read. So the question is bullsh***. Sorry.

Comment: Migrate to Physics SE.

Comment: I'm curious if you've done any research on this.  Articles aren't hard to find that explain various points where they conflict in layman's terms.    It's also rather broad.    Asking for a "list of conflicts" or explain some examples doesn't fit the model of this board.    I'm not a hard no, but I think this question is both too broad and shows a lack of effort.

Comment: Articles like this should be taken with a grain of salt, as they're probably not written by top scientists in the field, but they cover some of the basics:    http://io9.gizmodo.com/why-cant-einstein-and-quantum-mechanics-get-along-799561829   and  http://www.askamathematician.com/2009/12/q-howwhy-are-quantum-mechanics-and-relativity-incompatible/

Comment: @StephenG : It is an astrophysics question, so it belongs to both, astronomy and physics. I have taken the astronomy forum.

Comment: Quantum electrodynamics and relativistic quantum mechanics are the most precisely tested and accurate models available to us. You need to read your sources more carefully (or select better sources). I suggest they may be saying that merging quantum mechanics and *General* Relativity has not been done.

Comment: Read [Relativistic Quantum Mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_quantum_mechanics).  Short answer : yes we can merge SR and QM.  This is a general physics question, not specifically Astronomy, hence the migration suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no contradiction between special relativity and quantum mechanics. Quantum field theory fully merges special relativity and quantum mechanics to describe relativistic electrons and protons (quantum electrodynamics) and quarks (quantum chromodynamics).

The problems lie with merging general relativity and quantum mechanics.

Comment: In Brian Green's "Elegant Univers" it says special relativity does not merge quantum mechanics.

Comment: I think I would remember if Green made such an astonishing mistake in that book, so -- no. You must be misreading what he said.

Comment: @PeterErwin: I checked the statement and mentioned my mistakte.